# Getting Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my view, I am showing an image:

```
<img src="https://some-host/img1.jpg" onerror="showNoPhotoIcon(this);">
```

I have defined the function `showNoPhotoIcon` in a separate file called common.js

```
/*========== when image is not available ==========*/
function showNoPhotoIcon(image) {
    image.onerror = "";
    image.src = '/images/no-photo-icon.jpg'
    return true;
}
```

I am referencing common.js from my view, the following line is at the very bottom of my view (html page)

```
<script src="/Scripts/app/common.js"></script>
```

But the function is not accessible from the view, when the image is missing, the code tries to call `showNoPhotoIcon` function and I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: showNoPhotoIcon is not defined

**Update1:**

After I get the error, I tried to confirm the function is defined or not => it is.

[image]

**Update2:**

This seems to be a timing issue, because sometimes it works and sometimes it does not.

Comment: your code is probably trying to call `showNoPhotoIcon` in code ABOVE where you're loading common.js

Comment: Use an event listener instead? Rather than putting the js inside an attribute?

Comment: @JaromandaX: Yes, I believe so... but I have been told that it is better to add all the css files on top of html and .js files at bottom...

Comment: @evolutionxbox - an event listener may not necessarily be added in time to handle the error event

Comment: @JaromandaX aw poo... what if it gets created during a page event, like dom ready?

Comment: @HoomanBahreini - I tried dummying up the code with the handler at the bottom of the page, and it still handled the error - are you sure `showNoPhotoIcon` is in the global context? Go to the browser console, and type `console.log('showNoPhotoIcon')`

Comment: @evolutionxbox - it surprised me!

Comment: OK, so it's defined in global context - my "dummy" code was obviously flawed

Comment: @JaromandaX: Thanks, but the console.log('showPhotoIcon') says: undefined? Is it possible that I am losing binding because I am updating the image using ajax?

Comment: no, the console.log I told you to do was incorrect `console.log(showNoPhotoIcon)` - without the quotes ... or just type `showNoPhotoIcon` and enter - but I did further testing and it doesn't matter, your code will result in the error you've shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found having the handler code loaded in an external JS at the bottom of the body element makes the error handling inconsistent - but that's where you want JS code, which I agree with, so ...

One way to make the error handling consistent is as follows

First, don't use onerror attribute

```
<img src="https://some-host/img1.jpg" alt="" />
```

Secondly, change your `showNoPhotoIcon` as follows, because it will be called with an error event as the argument - this makes `removeEventListener` easy

```
function showNoPhotoIcon(e) {
    const image = e.target;
    image.removeEventListener('error', showNoPhotoIcon);
    image.src = '/images/no-photo-icon.jpg'
}
```

Add this code in the common.js

```
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(img => {
    if (img.naturalWidth === 0) {
        img.addEventListener('error', showNoPhotoIcon);
        img.src = img.src;
    }
});
```

This checks if the image width is 0, if so, it "reloads" it after attaching an error handler

It's a bit hacky in my view, you could also just assume if the width is 0 that the image doesn't exist, but, networks being networks, you never know - at least this way I think you are guaranteed to find and "fix" all broken images

Comment: "I've found having the handler code loaded in an external JS at the bottom of the body element makes the error handling inconsistent".. thanks for this, it explains the problem... are you able to share any link that you found about this please?

Comment: @HoomanBahreiniq - no, because it's just an observation based on my experience, nothing I've researched :p

Comment: Thanks again, I found a comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images/92819#92819) by Prestaul which says the same thing about on error handler.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini - yeah, too bad that question and answers were jquery based :D

Comment: Personally I think using inline js for handling error is a better solution, its shorter and easier to understand. I appreciate your answer, because it points out the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer explains the issue which is the error handler not being loaded when error happens.

In my case I changed the handler to use inline js:

```
<img src="https://some-host/img1.jpg" onError="this.onerror=null; this.src='/images/no-photo-icon.jpg';"
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code looks fine, maybe is the url in your `script` tag. Try to run your function in the same html page to double check. I don't see any reason to set `image.onerror = "";` and `return true;`

the best way should be to apply an event listener to the image, or images, so you don't have to write the function in the html tag.

```
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(image =>{
     image.addEventListener('error', (e) =>{
          // load the placeholder image
     });
});
```

Comment: a) `onerror` is not a correct event for addEventListener, and b) that won't work consistently since the error event could have fired before the javascript is even loaded